# implement geo / spatial / proximity search with php and mysql --- what have you done successfully

Tags: mysql, php, spatial

For my website's users, I want to implement a worldwide geo / spatial / proximity search with php and mysql.

I want to do this as simply and minimally as possible.

What is the minimum data I should capture (Country, State, City, Postal Code, etc.)?

There are dozens out-of-the-box and open-source solutions out there, with varying reviews. What have you tried that worked or did not work?

It's quite easy to implement such a thing for the U.S. (e.g., Google has some Zip code related proximity-solutions), but apparently if I want to go global, it's an order of magnitude more difficult. Have you tried (and was it worth-it) to code it from scratch?

Comment: If you launch into "find nearest" via latitude/longitude, read [_my blog_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng).  It handles worldwide, but is not easy.  The complexity is aimed at performance for large datasets.

Comment: @RickJames Thanks. Any thoughts on mySQL's Spatial Extensions?

Comment: Investigating `SPATIAL` is on my todo list.  (Along with a zillion other things.)

Answer (score 0):

I think using Latitude and Longitude is the best bet. Because when you go global, then zipcode might not be very accurate search. There is a very good article about using spatial indexes and the Point type database fields. You can read here
http://vinsol.com/blog/2011/08/30/geoproximity-search-with-mysql/

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE! As the OP is asking for people's experiences in doing this sort of thing, your statement of your opinion is more of a comment than an actual answer. As you build your reputation on this site, you'll gain the ability to comment on other peoples' questions and answers.

Comment: I do have the ability to add comments. But I think my comment is an actual answer, not a comment. I have referred to something which has the complete answer and I thought its no need to copy the solution from that link and paste it here so I just mentioned. the link

Comment: link not found ??

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, "Country, State, City, Postal Code, etc." are not spatial -- yet! What you want to capture is lat and long for a specific spatial reference system. Because people don't normally have that memorized, sometimes you have to settle. In light of that, is "Country, State, City, Postal Code, etc" useful? Yes. But, only because you can use that information as input to a geocoder to get back your GPS coordinates.

With this you can create a useful `POINT` that you can query and do proximity searching with. If you have no experience with GIS, I suggest the book *PostGIS in Action*. That book uses PostGIS which is the spatial extension for PostgreSQL (an all around better database). PostGIS has more features and is far more mature. It's also enjoys much wider adoption than MySQL spatial.

Note, as a special caveat at least currently MariaDB 10.x is *FAR* behind MySQL 8.x with regards to Spatial features.